# Migrating .Net 3.5 Compact Framework app to Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: .net, compact-framework

We have an app written to run on the .NET 3.5 Compact Framework. It runs primarily on Windows Mobile 5 & 6 devices and used SQL CE 3.5 for it's database.

We'd like to update the app to run on Windows 10 Mobile. I'm just starting to research app development for Windows 10 Mobile, so I was hoping to get some pointers to get me headed in the right direction. I'm just looking for high level advice on these two questions:

1. What Visual Studio project type would allow the most reuse of existing code and libraries?
2. Are there other project types that we should consider because they support non-Windows devices as well? Would I be able to reuse much code if I chose that project type? Is there a database solution that works with this project type cross platform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: UWP (supports a variety of modern Microsoft platforms)
2: Xamarin (supports Android and Ios) - resuse will depend on how well layered the original app is. You can use SQLite RDBMS